# Psych::DisallowedClass while updating a rails ActiveModel entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

This is a little weird, I am trying to update an ActiveModel entry via `rails_admin` console and updating any attribute on the  model throws the error `Psych::DisallowedClass`. Looks to me like the error is only thrown when the Model has some serialized fields. I  am not sure how the `Psych` library gets in the serialization scene under the hood, so looking for some pointers here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem after updating from rails 5.2.5 to 5.2.8.

I solved it by adding

`config.active_record.yaml_column_permitted_classes = [Symbol]`

in my `config/application.rb`.

Comment: I see it was now added as a default https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/45584/files

Answer (score -1):

From gem version *psych* 4.0, there are the strict approach for parsing the YAML files. So either use older versions of *psych*, pass the **permitted_classes** args to the *#load* method to allow the class, which you've got the exception for:

```rb
YAML.load(txt, permitted_classes: [Gem::Specification, Symbol])
```

The code is required to load YAML document with a specific non standard classes. Because loader prevents user from loading some unsafe classes. More information can be inferred from the sources of YAML.

Comment: Where to write this?

Comment: @RajeshPaul instead of YAML.load

Comment: This is when calling `serialize` not `YAML.load`

Comment: @Carl yaml load prevents user from loading some classes, so this required, please look at their sources